# Deferred object returns wrong result when loading data by $http

Tags: angularjs, deferred

I have a factory for loading `json` data from files using `$http` and `$q` in Angularjs.

```
App.factory('dataLoader', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
        var deferred = $q.defer(),
            data = {};

        return function (url){
            data = $http.get(url)
                .success(function(response){
                  deferred.resolve(response);
                })
                .error(function(){
                  deferred.reject('could not load template');
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }

    }]);
```

**Problem**: Everywhere i use this factory to load data, it returns only first usage result. for example:

Loading file 1:

```
dataLoader('json-folder/file-one.json').then(function(data){
        console.log('result1: ', data);
    });
```

Loading file 2:

```
dataLoader('json-folder/file-two.json').then(function(data){
        console.log('result2: ', data);
    });
```

In console i have contents of file-one.json only for both. How can i fix dataLoader factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A promise can only be resolved once. In addition, the angular services are singletons, so you are sharing the same promise for your whole app.

Try to create the promise inside the returned function.